# php before inserting one value to the database check the value in the database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have a form like this

```
<form id="formID" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[]"  value="Disk space"/>Disk space<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[]"  value="Color"/>Color<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="attribute[]"  value="Processor"/>Processor<br />
  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="save"/>
</form>
```

In mysql I have a database. The database structure is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ia_attributes` (
  `attribute_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=186 ;


INSERT INTO `ia_attributes` (`attribute_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES
(170, 'Color'),
(179, 'Disk space'),
(185, 'Processor');
```

As in the upper form you can see I have checkbox and I wanted to insert all the checkboxes at a time I made my code like this

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbname = 'database';
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname) or die ("no database");
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["save"]) && isset($_POST["type"])){
  $types = $_POST["type"];
  if(sizeof($types) > 0 ){
    foreach($types as $type){ 
      $qry= '';
      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ia_attributes` where `attribute_name`='".$type."'"); 
       if($result->num_rows == 1){
        echo "<script>
          alert('There are no fields to generate a report');
        </script>";
        }
        else {
          $qry = "INSERT INTO `ia_attributes`(`attribute_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES ('', '".$type."')";
          $sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
          if($sql_query) {
            echo "success";
          }
          else {
            echo "error";
          }
        }
     }
   }
}

?>
```

Here whatever I am trying to save its showing only the alertbox There are no fields to generate a report. The condition which has been given is not working. So can someone kindly tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to perform a query for database via mysqli_query, like: `select count(*) as cnt from ia_attributes` where attribute_name='$name'`. If cnt > 0, then you not need to insert into database. This check should be first inside a cycle.

Comment: you have to check with select query in where clause that WHERE attribute_name = '".$attribute."' if it returns num of rows then you show alert

Answer (score 0):

Do the select query with condition as attribute_name = selected color in your database. Then check number of results it returns. If it is greater than 0 then it already exist in your database, then display alert that it already exist.

```
if(isset($_POST["save"]) && isset($_POST["attribute"])){
    $attributes = $_POST["attribute"];
    if(sizeof($attributes) > 0 ){

        foreach($attributes as $attribute){
                $qry= '';
                $result = mysqli->query($con,"SELECT attribute_id FROM ia_attributes where attribute_name=$attribute")); 

                /* determine number of rows result set */
                $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
                if($row_cnt > 0){
                      echo "<script>
                      alert('There are no fields to generate a report');
                      </script>";
                 }
                 else{
                    $qry = "INSERT INTO `ia_attributes`(`attribute_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES ('', '".$attribute."')";
                    $sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
                    if($sql_query) {
                        echo "success";
                     }
                     else {
                         echo "error";
                     }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is showing error like `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` where `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;` has been used in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNIQUE Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) for attribute_name. If you add unique index to attribute_name and try to insert a value that has been already added, mysqli_query returns false.

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO `ia_attributes`(`attribute_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES ('', '".$attribute."')";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
if($sql_query) {
     echo "success";
} else {
     echo "'$attribute' has been already added";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could do:

```
<?php

function inArray($needle, $haystack) {
    if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
        return true;
    }

    foreach ($haystack as $stack) {
        if (is_array($stack) && in_array($needle, $stack)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '-Blue78-';
$database = 'test';

try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        throw new Exception('Database connection failed: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST["attribute"])) {
        $attributes = $_POST["attribute"];

        if (count($attributes)) {
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

                // check if record allready exists
                $result   = $mysqli->query('SELECT attribute_name FROM ia_attributes');
                $existing = $result->fetch_all();

                if (inArray($attribute, $existing)) {
                    echo 'Atribute allready exists';
                } else {
                    $query  = "INSERT INTO ia_attributes (attribute_name) VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($attribute) . "')";
                    $insert = $mysqli->query($query);

                    echo ($result) ? 'Success' : 'Failed';
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```